# Trouble Downloading Assets in Webots 2023a Version on MacOS

Tags: ros2, webots

I've recently downloaded and installed the Webots 2023a version on my MacOS. The installation process went through without any issues. However, I'm encountering a problem when I try to install tutorial or demo bots.

When I try to download the assets, the download seems to freeze, showing me a 0% progress, and doesn't progress from there. I've attached a screenshot below to give you a visual understanding of the issue.

Screenshot of issue

[image: Software stuck here]

Steps to reproduce this issue:

- Open Webots.
- Navigate to the tutorial or demo bots section.
- Try to download the assets.

I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

- Restarting the Webots application.
- Reinstalling the Webots application.
- Checking for updates to make sure I'm using the latest version of the software.
- Checking my internet connection to ensure it's stable.

None of the above steps seem to have solved the problem. I'm not sure if this is a bug with the software or if there's something wrong on my end.

If anyone has experienced a similar issue or knows of a potential solution, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you checked that you are not behind a global firewall preventing you to access github, for example, can you access this URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/master/projects/appearances/protos/Asphalt.proto ? Also, it could be that your local firewall is allowing your web browser, but preventing Webots to do so. Can you check it as well?

Comment: Thank you @OlivierMichel for quick reply.
------

Nope, not able to access https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/master/projects/appearances/protos/Asphalt.proto (is anything wrong with my location)

- Nope, there is no firewall within my browser or system as well.

Comment: So you are likely behind some global firewall. Where are you located? Can you try it from a different network location? Or through a VPN?

Comment: Above solution works. Currently, I'm based in INDIA, and it works as I've used VPN. Thanks @OlivierMichel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem typically means that you have a global firewall which prevents you from accessing online GitHub resources.

To confirm this, try to open [this URL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/e96905f5246b38db2a81f73f811f22d654fc8a01/projects/appearances/protos/Asphalt.proto).

If it doesn't work, then you have a firewall problem. You should try again from a different network location or from a VPN until you see the content of the URL.

Once this works, Webots should be able to download the resources it needs from GitHub and you problem will be resolved.

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*